# Xcode : cannot access to a NSString value set from another class

Tags: xcode, nsstring

I'm trying to pass a string variable from mainVC class to detailVC class, but when viewDidLoad is launched, myStringLabel is empty, where it should contain "Just a test".
I don't know why.

mainVC.m

```
#import "mainVC.h" 
@implementation mainVC 
@synthesize 

-(IBAction) openSecondController {
    //Ouverture de DetailVC
    detailVC *dVC = [[detailVC alloc] init];
    dVC.myStringLabel=@"Just a test";
    NSLog(@"dVC.myStringLabel before calling dVC :%@", dVC.myStringLabel);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"progDetailSegue" sender:nil];
    NSLog(@"dVC.myStringLabel after calling dVC :%@", dVC.myStringLabel) ;   
}
```

---

detailVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface detailVC : UIViewController {
 NSString *myStringLabel;
 IBOutlet UILabel *labelForString;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *labelForString;
@property (copy) NSString *myStringLabel;
```

---

detailVC.m

```
#import "detailVC.h"

@implementation detailVC
@synthesize myStringLabel, labelForString;

-(void) viewDidLoad {
NSLog(@"myStringLabel in viewDidLoad : %@", dVC.myStringLabel) ;
labelForString.text=myStringLabel;
}

-(IBAction) closeViewController {
//Fermeture com_mobilizProgramDetailViewController ouverte en Modal. 
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

---

NSLOG output :

```
2012-12-17 11:48:58.520 DataTransfert[5068:f803] dVC.myStringLabel before calling dVC : Just a test
2012-12-17 11:48:58.520 DataTransfert[5068:f803] myStringLabel in viewDidLoad : (null)
2012-12-17 11:48:58.520 DataTransfert[5068:f803] dVC.myStringLabel after calling dVC :Just a test
```

Answer (score 0):

in viewDidLoad, replace dvc.mystringlbl with self.mystringlbl

Comment: -(void) viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"myStringLabel in viewDidLoad : %@", myStringLabel) ;
    labelForString.text=myStringLabel;
    }

label is empty
NSSlog displays : myStringLabel in viewDidLoad : (null)

still no change

Comment: thats because storyboard keeps its own copy of instance, dVC is the new instance which you created but when you perform segue, storyborad show you its own instance of detaialVC, you have to take out that instance from storybard and set labelStr on that instance , somthing like    'UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];

detailVC *dVC = (detailVC*)[mainStoryboard 
                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"<Controller ID>"];

Comment: you can find "Controller ID" in your storyboard detailVC nib , i am assuming that the name of your storyboard is MainStoryboard.

Comment: Cannot find identifier in xcode 4.5.5 like in this image :
![Valid XHTML](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gzK2u.png)

Comment: select the viewController first, then you will see this property

Comment: if you dont have identifier then look for Storyboard ID in custom class section

Comment: I got error : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0xa12e8d0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'DKg-dG-bO1''
*** First throw call stack:

After a lot of search I don't see realy how to use that ID.

Comment: This is the image of my storyboard :
http://s7.postimage.org/l64a379jv/Capture_d_cran_2012_12_20_20_03_31.png

Comment: When I set "Storyboard ID" myself and check use "Storyboard ID" I get the same result : (null)

Comment: thx a lot @ iVishal for having tried to help me.
Problème was solved.
see my answer up !

Comment: @BlackMatrix glad you made it...merry christmas and happy new year ..:)

Answer (score 0):

@iVishal :

I founded an object ID like this : DKg-dG-bO1

for the viewController, it's what you where talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved.

I used another solution : -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

is called before viewController is displayed to pass data between to veiwcontrollers.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
detailVC *dVC = [segue destinationViewController];
dVC.myStringLabel=@"Just a test";
}
```

then it works !!!
in the log output, I get this result :

```
myStringLabel in viewDidLoad : Just a test
```

thx a lot @ iVishal for having tried to help me.

Happy new year to all !!